# Doing permutation of the dimension in a Boost multi_array

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, permutation

I'm writing a C++ program using [Boost multi_array library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html). I have a 4-dimensional array with, for example, the shape of `[5][10][100][20]`. And I would like to change the shape of the array to `[100][10][5][20]`. What would be the proper way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Can't you have special function to access with special index: `template <typename Array> decltype (auto) my_get(Array&& array, int c, int, b, int a, int d) { return array[a][b][c][d]; }` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you for your reply. True. This is definitely one way to solve the problem. But before I do this, I would like to check if there is already any functions for doing the dimension permutation.

Comment: @vsoftco Yes. I'd like to do permutation rather than simple reshape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you ask for a reshaping and not a permutation of the dimensions (those operations are not the same), then you can use the `reshape` member function of `boost::multi_array`, like so (example taken verbatim from the [Boost Multi-Array documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_reshape))

```
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;

array_type::extent_gen extents;
array_type A(extents[2][3][4]);
boost::array<array_type::index, 3> dims = {{4, 3, 2}};       
A.reshape(dims);
```

Full example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

int main()
{
    using array_type = boost::multi_array<double, 2>;

    array_type::extent_gen extents;
    array_type A(extents[1][2]); // 1 x 2 array

    A[0][0] = 1; A[0][1] = 2;
    std::cout << A[0][0] << ' ' << A[0][1] << '\n';

    boost::array<array_type::index, 2> dims = {{2,1}};
    A.reshape(dims); // reshape it to 2 x 1

    std::cout << A[0][0] << ' ' << A[1][0] << '\n'; // verify
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Wandbox</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FKxKnxVSUkZGkZ2g)

As for dimension permutation, as far as I know `boost::multi_array` does not have any function for that, so you'd need to write your own.